# Problema ao pegar um ID específico em botão

Tags: javascript, html

Estou tentando pegar um **botão** pelo **ID** e retornar o **value** dele. Por mais que os IDs tenham nomes diferentes, eles sempre retornam o mesmo **value**. Vou deixar um exemplo do código em HTML.

```html
<div class="tenis">
  <div class="preco">Valor R$: 50.00</div>
  <div>
    <p class="nomeTenis">Nike SB Stefan Janoski</p>
  </div>
  <button class="addCarrinho" id="tenis" value="stfjanoski" onclick="pegarId()"><a href="#">Página do Produto</a></button>
</div>
```

```html
<div class="tenis">
  <div class="preco">Valor R$: 50.00</div>
  <div class="nomeTenis">Air Force 1</div>
  <button class="addCarrinho" id="tenis" value="airforce1" onclick="pegarId()">Página do Produto</button>
</div>
```

Só peguei duas `divs` para exemplificar, porém o código completo tem umas 9 divs dentro um grid.

Estou utilizando o seguinte código em JS para pegar o `value` do botão:

```js
tenis = document.getElementById("tenis").value
```

Comment: Que valor você quer que retorne ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá!
O que acontece é que sua função pegarId é muito **específica**.
Como você está explicitando qual o ID, ele sempre vai pegar esse ID.

Você pode resolver de algumas formas:

```
<button id="tenis" pegarId("tenis") value="tenis nike">Botão</button>
<button id="camisas" pegarId("camisas") value="camisa polo1">Botão</button>
```

Isso mantendo sua função do mesmo jeito.

Ou você faz passando um `this` por parâmetro na função e acessando diretamente a propriedade value.

Fiz um código de exemplo em: [Exemplo com o this](https://jsfiddle.net/qb1ft8o0/)

Comment: Obrigado Alisson eu já tinha visto a opção de resolver usando o this.value, mas mesmo assim grato por sua ajuda